# This Riddle Should Be Easy

Tags: language

> I am a word with rhyming parts,
>
> Each part a word if spoken aloud.
>
> The first is to bully
>
> The last is to steal
>
> And spoken together, a pleasant meal.
>
> What am I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are a

> picnic

I am a word with rhyming parts.  Each part a word if spoken aloud.

> 'pic' and 'nic' are not words, but sound like:

The first is to bully

> pick, as in 'to pick on'

The last is to steal

> nick, as in 'to nick something'

And spoken together, a pleasant meal.

> A picnic is a type of (often pleasant) meal!

Title: This Riddle Should Be Easy

> Idiomatically, something that is 'no picnic' is not easy.  So, it follows that a picnic should be quite easy.

Comment: Ninja'd! You are too quick for me.

Comment: And here I was, trying to rhyme 'rob' 

Comment: Did you get the title?

Comment: ...not until now.  Will elaborate

Comment: Very nice title! That was quite a stealth clue.

Comment: I almost changed that title, too, because we don't want people to put evaluations of difficulty into their titles.  Glad I didn't :)

Comment: @Rubio I was hopeful that mods would say, “that title is so bad, it must be intentional.”

Comment: @kedarguru With some of the stuff we see, we learn with depressing speed that such faith is all too often misplaced :)